# Volume of 3d shape using numerical integration with scipy

Tags: scipy, geometry, numerical-integration

I have written a function for computing volume of intersection of a cube and a half-space and now I'm writing tests for it.

I've tried computing the volume numerically like this:

```
integral = scipy.integrate.tplquad(lambda z, y, x: int(Vector(x, y, z).dot(normal) < distance),
                                   -0.5, 0.5,
                                   lambda x: -0.5, lambda x: 0.5,
                                   lambda x, y: -0.5, lambda x, y: 0.5,
                                   epsabs=1e-5,
                                   epsrel=1e-5)
```

... basically I integrate over the whole cube and each point gets value 1 or 0 based on if it is inside the half space.
This gets very slow (more than several seconds per invocation) and keeps giving me warnings like

```
scipy.integrate.quadpack.IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent
```

Is there a better way to calculate this volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Integration

Integration of a discontinuous function is problematic, especially in multiple dimension. Some preliminary work, reducing the problem to an integral of a continuous function, is needed. Here I work out the height (top-bottom) as a function of x and y, and use `dblquad` for that: it returns in `36.2 ms`.

I express the plane equations as `a*x + b*y + c*z = distance`. Some care is needed with the sign of c, as the plane could be a part of the top or of the bottom.

```
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
distance = 0.1
a, b, c = 3, -4, 2  # normal
zmin, zmax = -0.5, 0.5  # cube bounds

# preprocessing: make sure that c > 0
# by rearranging coordinates, and flipping the signs of all if needed

height = lambda y, x: min(zmax, max(zmin, (distance-a*x-b*y)/c)) - zmin
integral = dblquad(height, -0.5, 0.5, 
                   lambda x: -0.5, lambda x: 0.5,
                   epsabs=1e-5, epsrel=1e-5)
```

#### Monte Carlo methods

Picking sample points at random (Monte Carlo method) avoids the issues with discontinuity: the accuracy is about the same for discontinuous as for continuous functions, the error decreases at the rate `1/sqrt(N)`  where N is the number of sample points.

The [polytope package](https://tulip-control.github.io/polytope/) uses it internally. With it, a computation could go as

```
import numpy as np
import polytope as pc
a, b, c = 3, 4, -5  # normal vector
distance = 0.1 
A = np.concatenate((np.eye(3), -np.eye(3), [[a, b, c]]), axis=0)
b = np.array(6*[0.5] + [distance])
p = pc.Polytope(A, b)
print(p.volume)
```

Here A and b encode the halfspaces as `Ax<=b`: the first fix rows are for faces of the cube, the last is for the plane.

To have more control over precision, either implement Monte-Carlo method yourself (easy) or use [`mcint`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mcint/) package (about as easy).

#### Polytope volume: a task for linear algebra, not for integrators

You want to compute the volume of a **polytope**, a convex body formed by intersecting halfspaces. This ought to have an algebraic solution. SciPy has [HalfspaceIntersection](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection.html#scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection) class for these but so far (1.0.0) does not implement finding the volume of such an object. If you could find the vertices of the polytope, then the [ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull) class could be used to compute the volume.  But as is, it seems that SciPy spatial module is no help. Maybe in a future version of SciPy...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to avoid branching the code like this because I feel like it's creating too much space for an error :-). I was going for dumb, slow and bulletproof :-). But I'll probably have to go this way if I can't figure out anything better.

Comment: Easy. Good and cheap :-). Btw do you think I could get a reasonable result with just manually sampling the "inside" function at regular steps over the cube?

Comment: Sampling a cube? 1000 samples in each direction is 1000000000 function evaluations.

Comment: Polytope seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: ... Actually `polytope` only does some randomized sampling integral internaly, with fixed number of 3000 samples for 3D data. That's too imprecise for me :-)

Comment: Oops, I should have looked more carefully. Hard to believe that there is no algebraic solution available. Please unaccept this answer for now, to increase their chance someone else will look at it.

Comment: There is one available, that's what I'm testing :-). I'll go with homebrew sampling estimate, 1e6 jittered samples should be good enough.

Comment: The error of Monte-Carlo method is ~1/sqrt(N) so you'll have ~0.001 error. If this is acceptable, maybe adjust the SciPy error bound accordingly? Also, MC method is already implemented in [mcint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mcint/), though of course isn't hard to do from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Integration of characteristic function is mathematically correct, but not practical. That is because most integration schemes are designed to integrate *polynomials* to some degree exactly, and in consequence all "relatively smooth" functions reasonably well. Characteristic functions, however, are everything but smooth. Polynomial-style integration will get you nowhere.

A much better-suited approach is to build a discretized version of the domain first, and then simply sum up the volumes of the little tetrahedra.

Discretization in 3D can be done, for example, with [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh) (a project of mine interfacing [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/)). The below code discretizes the cut-off cube to

[image]

You can increase the precision by decreasing `max_cell_circumradius` and/or `max_edge_size_at_feature_edges`, but meshing will take longer then. Moreover, you could specify "feature edges" to resolve the intersection edges exactly. This would give you the exactly correct result even with the coarsest cell size.

```py
import pygalmesh
import numpy


c = pygalmesh.Cuboid([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1])
h = pygalmesh.HalfSpace([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 4.0, 10.0)
u = pygalmesh.Intersection([c, h])
mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(
    u, max_cell_circumradius=3.0e-2, max_edge_size_at_feature_edges=1.0e-2
)


def compute_tet_volumes(vertices, tets):
    cell_coords = vertices[tets]
    a = cell_coords[:, 1, :] - cell_coords[:, 0, :]
    b = cell_coords[:, 2, :] - cell_coords[:, 0, :]
    c = cell_coords[:, 3, :] - cell_coords[:, 0, :]
    # omega = <a, b x c>
    omega = numpy.einsum("ij,ij->i", a, numpy.cross(b, c))
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume
    return abs(omega) / 6.0

vol = numpy.sum(compute_tet_volumes(mesh.points, mesh.get_cells_type("tetra")))
print(f"{vol:.8e}")
```

```
8.04956436e-01
```

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that boundary of the half-space is given by $\{(x, y, z) \mid ax + by + cz + d = 0 \}$ with $c \not= 0$, and that the half-space of interest is that below the plane (in the $z$-direction), then your integral is given by

```
scipy.integrate.tplquad(lambda z, y, x: 1,
                        -0.5, 0.5,
                        lambda x: -0.5, lambda x: 0.5,
                        lambda x, y: -0.5, lambda x, y: max(-0.5, min(0.5, -(b*y+a*x+d)/c)))
```

Since at least one of $a$, $b$, and $c$ must be non-zero, the case $c = 0$ can be handled by changing coordinates.

Comment: I think this doesn't work, because you only use the plane equation and ignores the orientation of the half-space.For example if my input was half-space $z > -0.2$, then the equation would be $z - 0.2 = 0$, same as when the input was $z < -0.2$ (and both of these have different result).

Comment: @cube: It handles that just fine, as you can readily verify: let `a = 0`, `b = 0`, `c = 1`, and the cases `d = 0.2` and `d = -0.2` will give results of `0.3` and `0.7` respectively.

Comment: Right, I didn't think of the changing coordinates bit.

Comment: I also just fixed a typo as `a` and `c` had been swapped around, and I can see how that could cause some confusion.

Comment: @SFTP: That's true.