# python pygalmesh can't make working exemple

Tags: python, mesh

I am trying to use pygalmesh for a project of mine. Basically, i need to create a cube and then subtract part of it in tube form. I have a couple of things i can't get to work. First of, i need to create a cube and the function used in pygalmesh is Cuboid as in :

```
pygalmesh.Cuboid([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1])
```

i tried this exact line of code since i found it in an answer made by the creator of pygalmesh in this post : [Volume of 3d shape using numerical integration with scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338406/volume-of-3d-shape-using-numerical-integration-with-scipy#)

But even with that line, i get the error :
RuntimeError: CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Explanation: Error: the sizing field is null at corner (0 0 0)

I went into the github repo to try and find how the functions works but i can only find the file that says :

```
from _pygalmesh import Cuboid
```

and nothing more. How can i create a cube using pygalmesh then? If possible, i would like to find how to work with all type of volume of pygalmesh, currently i can only reproduce the ones in the exemple on github.

Also, in the same post above ([Volume of 3d shape using numerical integration with scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338406/volume-of-3d-shape-using-numerical-integration-with-scipy#)) in the answer using pygalmesh, the code uses a line about cell size (cell_size=3.0e-2) around line 10. But every time i try to add this argument to my function mesh, i get the error :
TypeError: generate_mesh() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cell_size'

But i am using the same function as he is?

Is there an update removing some functions that i am missing, i am currently using the latest version of pygalmesh. Here is a simple code showing the error for cell size. If I change Ball for Cuboid, i get the Cuboid error instead.

```
import numpy
import pygalmesh

mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(
    pygalmesh.Ball([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 25.0), cell_size=3.0e-2
)
print(mesh)
mesh.write("out2.vtk")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an outdated version of pygalmesh. `cell_size` has been removed a while ago. Try using `max_cell_circumradius` or `max_edge_size_at_feature_edges`.

```py
import numpy
import pygalmesh

mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(
    pygalmesh.Ball([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 25.0), max_cell_circumradius=1.0e-2
    )
print(mesh)
mesh.write("out.vtk")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. But what about the Cuboid part? Also you said i am using an outdated version but a version to recent since cell_size was removed a while ago? So i am using a version too recent then? As for the mesh arguments you are mentioning, i am trying to build a really big cube (500x500x500 and would like the cell_size to be way bigger but when am i using those arguments, they seem to cap out and force me to build a mesh with a really really high density which takes forever to build.

Comment: What _about_ the cuboid part? Have you tried the suggestion?

Comment: Yes i tried the suggestion but like i said, i have no problem creating a ball or using those mesh arguments, what i need is to make a cuboid and i can't use the function pygalmesh.Cuboid([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0,1.0,1.0]).
I get the error :
RuntimeError: CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
File: /Users/jeremie/anaconda3/envs/pygalmesh/include/CGAL/Mesh_3/Protect_edges_sizing_field.h
Line: 453
Explanation: Error: the sizing field is null at corner (0 0 0)

Your suggestion did not answer any of my 2 questions.

Comment: `max_edge_size_at_feature_edges`